# Getting This Error When Trying To Connect To MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPKpl.png)Not sure why Im getting this error as it was working the last time I opened my project but this is what I get when I attempt to connect to my database.[mongo error,jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GZGe.png)

Error Code

```
PS C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\server> node server.js
Server is running on port:${port}

(node:18576) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to 
the MongoClient constructor.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:438
          new MongoNetworkError(
          ^

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-02.qqrcr.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
    at Connection.messageHandler (C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:359:19)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at processMessage (C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:451:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:620:15)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:313:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:288:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:227:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError'
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:562:14
    at C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:1009:9
    at callback (C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:75:5)
    at C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:147:27
    at C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\auth\scram.js:185:14
    at _callback (C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:328:7)
    at Connection.messageHandler (C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:359:9)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at processMessage (C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:451:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:620:15)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:313:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:288:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:227:10)
PS C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\server>
```

Comment: here is my code too

Comment: Can you share your code? Looks like an authentication failure.

Comment: You have an auth failure. Show us your connection string. Change the username and password with a dummy ones before posting, of course.

Comment: here is my connection string ATLAS_URI=mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.qqrcr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority